# Netbeans - github - jars from local filesystem

Tags: java, git, netbeans

Hello i have a ear based webapplication in Netbeans 8.0.2.

I have some external jar-s from my local filesystem for example C:\myproject\jars\stuff.jar

In my project's EJB modules properties\build\packaging i have checked the "Compress Jar File" and package require jars to EJB jar checkboxes. 
And in my project war module i have done it also.

I create a commit then push it to github, but when i try to clone or try to pull repo from github by another computer, it shows error by missing jars which are pointing to local file system at the host libary like : C:\myproject\jars\stuff.jar which libary doesn't exist on the other comupter..

Does anybody has any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Assuming you're using the default "ant" backed project and are adding the libraries to the project via the "libraries" node, then you need to ensure you are using relative paths.  In the `Add JAR/Folder` dialog, there is an option called `Reference as` with some `JRadioButtons`, make sure you use the relative path...and the jars are stored relative to your project.  You might consider using a Maven based project instead, in order to manage the dependencies

Comment: Thank you i tried to delete all my external jars and then added again with relative path.. after add push it to github. Now we tried to clone it again from zero, but the external jars has still broken reference message.. :( the external jars are in my computer on my local filesystem.. should i copy them to the project and load them from the project libary?

Comment: You need to make sure the Jars are in the same place (relative to the project), I normally create a `lib` directory in the project, but you might not want to have the binaries in your repo